# Prove this congruence

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Let $p$ be a prime of the form $4k+3$ and $m$ an even positive integer less than $p-1$. Prove that $$1^m+2^m+\cdots+\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^m \equiv \left(\frac{p+1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{p+1}{4}\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac{p+1}{4}\right)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod p$$ WITHOUT doing it by showing that both sides are divisible by $p$.

I couldn't solve this

Comment: The LHS _should_ be the set of all quadratic residues $\bmod p$ (or closely related); you can consider attacking the problem from that angle.